# controlling gpio on Ubuntu 20.04 64 bit arm Raspberry Pi

Tags: kernel, 20.04, hardware, ram, arm64

I wrote a program in C which uses the gpio pins on a Raspberry Pi. When I wrote the program, it ran fine on Ubuntu 18.04 armhf (32 bit). Now, however, on my Raspberry pi 4, running Ubuntu 20.04 arm64, I get the following error when running with sudo:

```
    initPeripherals: mmap gpio failed (Operation not permitted)
```

As I understand it, this error is a result of the kernel being compiled with the option

```
    CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y
```

How can I fix this problem, without recompiling my kernel? I have tried setting iomem=relaxed and strict-devmem=0 to no avail. I have also tried adding rules to /etc/udev/rules.d/ which doesn't seem to work either. Also, I have tried changing group membership around, but again, I'm running this as root with sudo.

Edit: 18.04 arm64 kernel works just fine. I guess I'll be content with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's permissions issue.

```
$ sudo apt install rpi.gpio-common
```

After that you should be able to

```
$ echo "21" > /sys/class/gpio/export
$ echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio21
$ echo "21" > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

If so there should be no problem to work with gpio from C code.

The package only installs these rules file. I saw on the web solutions providing udev rules, but most of them don't work.

```
$ cat /lib/udev/rules.d/60-rpi.gpio-common.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="bcm2835-gpiomem", KERNEL=="gpiomem", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpiochip*", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown root:dialout /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport ; chmod 220 /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport'"
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpio*", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown root:dialout /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value ; chmod 660 /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value'"
```

You can also manually put the file to `/etc/udev/rules.d/`.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer, explaining how the installation of this package will resolve any permissions issue?